# Retrieve a file from browser using API gateway, AWS LAMBDA and S3

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

The setup is using S3 as a storage, API gateway for the rest endpoint and Lambda (Python) for get/fetch of file in S3.

I'm using Boto3 for the Lambda function (Python) to check if the file exists in S3, and I was able to download it but being stored in Lambda machine ("/tmp"). The API Gateway can trigger the lambda function already. Is there a way that once the lambda function is triggered then the download will happen in the browser?

Thanks!

Comment: You will run into a limitation of 6MB when you handle through Lambda and API Gateway limits you to 10MB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how we did it:

**Check and Redirect:**

API Gateway --> Lambda (return 302)

**Deliver Content:**

CloudFront --> S3

Check for S3 existence with Lambda returning a 302 to cloudfront. You can also return Signed URL from Lambda with a valid time to access the URL from CloudFront.

Hope it helps.

Comment: please provide a detailed answer

Comment: If you need more detailed answer you need to study more documentation from aws. It is unnecessary for the question as it just need the concept of how to do it. Not how to implement it. Implementing it will be a project.

Comment: Yes, that's the initial plan to do it but since API gateway now supports binary transfer then it's possible to return the file itself thru API gateway but haven't found a solution for it. So I guess, I'll just use apre-signed url then redirect it.

Comment: That is the cleanest way to overcome any limitations with AWS Services and make it scalable. Glad it helped.